# Changing mesh3d material to lines in RGL

Tags: r, rgl

Just noticed that I can no longer create change a cube3d() material to lines by changing the materials list inside the object. This still works for color, though. The code snipper below used to create a solid green cube, and then after changing the 3 parameters, a blue outline of a cube.

I use this feature when I'm drawing many objects with 'shapelist3d()' and want to outline some of them. Is there a new way to selectively change some object materials?

Using rgl v0.107.14 and R 4.1.1, but noticed with previous versions as well.

```r
library(rgl)

cb <- cube3d(col = "green") #Solid green cube

rgl::shapelist3d(list(cb))

cb$material$color <- "blue"
cb$material$front <- "line"
cb$material$back <- "line"

rgl::shapelist3d(list(cb)) #Solid blue cube, but should be wire
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug in `shade3d`, which is called by `shapelist3d`.

There are 3 ways to specify a shape should be drawn in outline:

- as a material property (which you used)
- as an argument to shade3d
- by calling wire3d instead of shade3d

Unfortunately, the third method is being assumed:  `shade3d` is called with no arguments, but it is ignoring the material property.

There are a couple of workarounds for this.  You could keep the outline objects in a separate list, and call `lapply(outlinelist, wire3d)` to draw them in outline.  Or you could write your own replacement for `shade3d` to fix the bug, e.g.

```
myshade3d <- function(x, front = "filled", back = "filled", ...) {
  if (!is.null(x$material$front)) front <- x$material$front
  if (!is.null(x$material$back)) back <- x$material$back
  rgl::shade3d(x, front = front, back = back, ...)
}
```

then call it as `lapply(fulllist, myshade3d)`.

Edited to add:  This bug is now fixed in the devel version, installable (if you have the prerequisites!) as

```
remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")
```